I am working on an odoo project, and now I need to change all the places where odoo appears in the project code, is there any good way?
I am working on an odoo project, and now I need to change all the places where odoo appears in the project code, is there any good way?
I hope the code will still work after the change,However, the project cannot work properly after I modify it. I hope someone can provide a good solution

That seems a little dubious. Hence my cheeky answer: Just don't use Odoo.
